# Test class for a check if null method

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I've been trying to write a test class for a method that checks if an object is null.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/register-sequence')
global class RestClassToTest {
    @HttpPost
    global static void RegisterSequence() { 
...
...
if(CustomObjectNeeded == null){
            system.debug('Error');
            msgError = 'Null data.';
            SalesforceError[] errs = new SalesforceError[]{new SalesforceError(false, 'the recieved argument is null.','')};
            RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(errs));
            return;
            
        }else if ......  
}
    public class CustomObjectNeeded{
        public String idRecord;
        public String SequenceNumber;
    }
```

However I can´t get it covered in my test class

```
    @istest static void RegisterSequenceifNull()
    {
        RestClassToTest.CustomObjectNeeded object;
        //object without a 'new' since I'm trying to get inside the condition of a null object
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
        RestResponse response = new RestResponse();
        request.requestUri = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/apexrest/register-sequence';
        request.httpMethod = 'POST';
        request.requestBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serializePretty(object));
        RestContext.request = request;
        RestContext.response= response;
        RestClassToTest.RegisterSequence();
                                                            
    }
```

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong here?
Many thanks.

Comment: You chopped out your deserialization logic (how you're parsing `CustomObjectNeeded`), so we're missing a critical piece of what we would need to help you. Depending on how you're doing things, it might not be possible to test this logic (i.e. you don't need to worry about it). If you would, please [edit] in the part where you're parsing the incoming data.

Comment: Many thanks @sfdcfox although the code I sent here was incomplete I realized that when using **RegisterSequence()** I was instancing a **CustomObjectNeeded** using IDs and fields from Leads and Contancts, hence as long as I was using the method I will at least have empty data but never null, therefore that comparison was not needed at all and couldn't be covered even if I wanted to. Thanks again and sorry for the incomplete question I sent, I'm just getting started on Apex and this was such a newbie mistake.

Comment: Not a problem. That's what we're here for! Feel free to ask a new question if you ever need help, we'll be here.

Answer (score 0):

There was no need to test that logic since that 'if statement' was not relevant at all and I should've ignored it.

Even when aiming for high code-coverage test clases, I should have checked first if my logic could be tested (or even needed in the first place).